# Getting method error using Ruby "NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What this does is the app gets the Steam Market Price of an item. I accidentally deleted the database.db, and since then, the same error has been consistently popping up. I'm wondering what is wrong with the code. Maybe I have overlooked some parts of the code.

It appears that the problem is in the index.erb file.

### App.rb

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?
require 'open-uri'
require "sinatra/json"
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require './models/bookmark.rb'
#require './models.rb'

enable :sessions

post '/signup' do
 @user = User.create(mail:params[:mail], password:params[:password],
 password_confirmation:params[:password_confirmation])

 if @user != nil
 session[:user]=@user.id
 end
 redirect '/'
end

post '/signin' do
 user = User.find_by_mail(params[:mail])
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
 session[:user] = user.id
 end
 redirect '/'
end

get '/signout' do
 session[:user] = nil
redirect '/'
end




get '/' do
  userid = session[:user]

  if userid==nil
  redirect '/home'

  else

  @user = User.find_by_id(userid)
  @bookmark = @user.bookmarks
  end
  erb :inde1x
end
=begin
 userid = session[:user]

  if userid==nil
  redirect '/home'

  else

  @user = User.find_by_id(userid)
  @bookmarks = @user.bookmarks

  end
=end


get '/signin' do
 erb :signin
end
get '/signup' do
 erb :signup
end



#get '/' do
# @bookmarks = Bookmark.all

 #erb :index
#end
post '/create' do
 url1 = params[:url]
 url2 = URI.escape(url1)
 priceurl = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open('http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q='+url2))
 erlength= priceurl.css('#searchResultsRows').text

 if erlength.length >150

 priceurl2= p priceurl.search("#resultlink_0")[0].attributes["href"].text

 texturl= priceurl2[46..-1]
 else

 redirect '/'
 end



 redirect '/api/site?url='+texturl

end


get '/api/site' do
 rawurl = params[:url]
 url1 = URI.escape(rawurl)
# url2 = URI.escape(url1)
 logger.info url
 price = open('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name='+url1).read
 data = JSON.load(price)
 pricecheck= data['median_price']
 #priceooo= pricecheck[1..6]



 imagerine = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/'+url1))

 imagebomb= imagerine.at_css('.market_listing_largeimage img')['src']

 images= '<img src="'+imagebomb+'"/>'

 html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/'+url1))
 title = html.css('title').text
 titles = title.sub(/^Steam Community Market :: Listings for / , '')
 Bookmark.create(title: titles, url: " Average Price: "+ pricecheck, pricecheck: images, user_id: session[:user] )
 redirect '/'



end
post '/delete/:id' do
 Bookmark.find(params[:id]).destroy
 redirect '/'
end


post '/usercreateauth' do
  Bookmark.create(title: params[:password], url: params[:username])
  #redirect '/'+params[:username]

end


get '/home' do
 erb :home
end
```

### Part of the index.erb

#### This is where the problem originates.

For some reason, "each" is no longer a method.

```
<div class="main">

    <div id="app">  
    <h4>Input the item's name into the box</h4>
    <p>Ex: Awp Asiimov Well Worn,  </p>
    <div style="height:20vh; overflow:hidden;"><img style="width:20vw;" src="/name.png"/></div>
    <form action="/create" method="post" id="frm" class="">
 <!--label for="url">Hash Value</label>
 <input  name="url" id="url"-->
 <label for="url">Item Name</label>
 <input  name="url" id="url">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit" class="btn btn-primary submit"></input>
 </form>
 <br>

 <div class="container-fluid">

 <div class="row">
 <% @bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
 <div class="containerbox">
<p><%= bookmark.pricecheck%></p>
 <p><%= bookmark.title %><b id="price"><%= bookmark.url %></b></p>

 <span>
 <form action="/delete/<%= bookmark.id %>" method="post">
 <input class="delete" type="submit" value="x">
 </form>
 </span>

 </div>
 <% end %>
```

### Bookmark.rb

```
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['DATABASE_URL']||"sqlite3:db/development.db")
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

unless ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production'
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("sqlite3:db/development.db")
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :bookmarks
 has_secure_password
 validates :password,
 length: {in: 1..10}
end
```

## Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['DATABASE_URL']||"sqlite3:db/development.db")
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

unless ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production'
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("sqlite3:db/development.db")
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :bookmarks
 has_secure_password
 validates :password,
 length: {in: 1..10}
end
```

Comment: I assume the line is `@bookmarks.each`? This is weird because `@bookmarks = @user.bookmarks` is supposed to return an empty Array `[]` if there are no bookmarks to the user. Can you run the initialization code in the console and check what is the value of `@bookmarks`? Unless, of course, the execution path to rendering `index.erb` does not initializes `@bookmarks` at all.. That's probably the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying! What's an initialization code?

Comment: I mean - in the scenario in which you get that error, run the controller code line by step from the console until you get all the ivars initialized just before the view starts rendering. Then try `@bookmarks` to get the value. It should be nil otherwise that error won't be reproduced. Through this process you'll likely understand why it's nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice in your `App.rb` that you have a line `@bookmark = @user.bookmarks`. Note that `@bookmark` is singular. Then in the view template you try to run `@bookmarks.each` (plural = a completely unrelated instance variable name). If the code doesn't recognize the name `@bookmarks`, the object will default to `nil` which doesn't understand the method `.each`. Check your variable names carefully!, this is a common source of errors and this particular error ("Unknown method [some method name] on Nil::NilClass") is a very common one in Rails development.

On a more general note, the format of your `App.rb` file looks strange to me. It looks like this is serving the role of both `routes.rb` (connects each URL route to a controller action) and the controller (which takes the request inputs and prepare all variables required for the view to render properly). Is there a reason your app is structured in this way? If not, I highly recommend you get familiar with Rails' standard structure for routes & controllers; there are good reasons why those two pieces of code are typically kept in separate places. (Among other things, it may make errors like this easier to troubleshoot!)

Comment: Thanks! Ill take a look at the variable names once more! I'll also try to clean up App.rb.

Comment: It worked! "@bookmark" in app.rb had to be plural! Thanks for pointing this out!